# How to access external json data via url link in ReactJS

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to access the data I have via external url, but I am not getting any output.
In my solution I want to use React hooks so first, I pointed to the url

```
const dataInfo = "secretURLwithJSONData";
```

than I am using useState and useEffect functions in my component

```
const reactComponent = () => {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        getDataInfo();
    }, []);

    const getDataInfo = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(dataInfo);
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        setUserData(jsonData);
    };
```

And the last step is that I am pointing out at the data from JSON

```
<h5 >{userData.name}</h5>
```

Example of JSON in url:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Name"
      }
    }
    ]   
}
```

As you can see is is an array of objects, so there are of course more data, but it should give you an idea of the structure.

jsonData in console:

[jsonData HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moCtN.png)

Comment: Try `userData.data.attributes.name`

Comment: @MrCoconut looks like data is an array `data[0]`

Comment: I tried already unfortunately it gives me type error: ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: You should use debugger/react developer tools to check how the state of your app looks like

Comment: Can you please check console.log(jsonData)

Comment: @Sam, I updated my post check the output.

Comment: @Jane you are missing the name prop in attribute JSON, you have the first name and last name based on the image you added. Maybe you need to combine both

Comment: @Sam there is also an attribute with "name", where is together First and Last name.

Comment: if you already that prop exists, you can use the map to loop through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1. You're accessing the data wrong (at least given the example above)
2. You're accessing it before it's made available

Since you're dealing with an async operation (fetching data) you need to make sure your data exists before accessing it in JSX:

```
{userData.data ? <h5>{userData.data[0].attributes.name}</h5> : 'No data yet'}
```

And since your data is an array, you'll need to map through it (untested code, but you get the idea):

```
{userData.data ? {userData.data.map((data) => 
 <h5 >
  {data.attributes.name}</h5> 
)}
: 'No data yet'}
```

Keep in mind you're also accessing a deeply nested object there, so you should make sure all those levels exist, unless you trust your API enough that it won't change.

Using [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is useful for this.

Comment: Thank you for the post @Obed, I will sure check it out. The way you posted works, but since it accessing [0] I am getting only the first data out, but I need to loop through all of them. Is it relevant to use .map ? Also, if there is some other- more safe solution you can link to I would love to read about it, thank you !

Comment: Yeah, you need to use map. I updated my answer to reflect that :). Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: It does solve the issue @Obed, so I will accept the answer, but it is still missing the unique key, if you can just make comment, that others knows :) Thank you for the answer.